# Indicating Required Fields in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a PHP file of a process form that indicates the required fields when processed. The code that I have is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .error{color: #FF0000;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['fullname']) && $_POST['fullname'] != "") {
        $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] != "") {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['feedback']) && $_POST['feedback'] != "") {
        $text= $_POST['feedback'];
    }

    $nameErr = $emailErr = "";
    $name = $email = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == POST) {
        if (empty($_POST["fullname"])){
            $nameErr = "Name is required";
        } else {
            $name = test_input($_POST["fullname"]);
        }
        if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
            $emailErr = "Email is required";
        } else {
            $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        }
    }
    ?>
        <h1>Customer Feedback</h1>
        <p1>Please tell us what you think</p1><br><br>
        <form method='POST' action='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>' >
            <p1>Your name:</p1><br>
            <input type="text" name="fullname" value="<?php echo $fullname; ?>"><br><br>
            <p1>Your email address:</p1><br>
            <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"><br><br>
            <p1>Your feedback:</p1><br>
            <textarea rows="5"  cols="50" name="feedback"><?php echo $text;?></textarea><br><br>
            <input type="submit" Value="Send Feedback"><br><br>
            <?php
                error_reporting(E_ALL);


                $name = $_POST['fullname'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $feed = $_POST['feedback'];

                if (empty($name)) 
                {
                    echo "Please enter your name, email and feedback.";
                }
                if (empty($email)) 
                {
                    echo "Please enter your email and feedback.";
                }
                if (empty($feed))
                {
                    echo "Please enter feedback.";
                }
                if (!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($feed))
                {
                    echo "You have inserted the correct data";
                }
            ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, when I run it on Chrome, I got a server error 500 saying that

> The website encountered and error while retrieving process_4.php. It maybe down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

The other PHP files that I've made leading up to this point have all worked correctly and I don't know why this one isn't.

Comment: Check your error logs to know what is happening.

Comment: Seems to work here: https://eval.in/522323 The only thing I see that's a little disconcerting is this: `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == POST` The _POST_ text in that comparison evaluates first as a constract, thena as an implicit string of "POST"; if `define('POST', 'whatever');` ever gets set, you could get something unexpected. But that won't cause a Server 500 error.

Comment: I went onto 'Diagnose errors' and the problems that were found were 'Windows received an HTTP error message: 403 (Forbidden) from "sharedweb.co.uk"

Comment: Are you getting the error when you try and load the page the first time or when you submit the form? It doesn't look like you've defined the function `test_input` so when checking the form data on post that will fail.

Comment: I get the error when I load the page the first time

Comment: Check the server logs, not browser logs. Are you getting a 403 or a 500? Is `sharedweb.co.uk` your domain? That doesn't seem to be registered..

Comment: How would I go about checking the server logs? And that is my domain and it has been registered.

Comment: Other services don't recognize it as being registered yet.. https://www.godaddy.com/domains/searchresults.aspx?checkAvail=1&domainToCheck=sharedweb.co.uk or `whois sharedweb.co.uk` gives  `No match for "sharedweb.co.uk"`. Checking the error logs depends on your server configuration. Could be `/var/log/httpd/..` Use the `@` to direct comments to me..